# TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined at DirectionPage.CalculateDistanceWithGoogleApi

Tags: javascript, api

I have a problem when I try to calculate the distance between two positions on ionic 5, I have this error:

> Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined.

Need help please.

I use this tuto.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju38qE8WkJ4

the ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
var google;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-direction',
  templateUrl: './direction.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./direction.page.scss'],
})

export class DirectionPage {

  constructor(public platform: Platform) 
  {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      this.CalculateDistanceWithGoogleApi();
    })
   }

  CalculateDistanceWithGoogleApi(){

    ''var gps1 = new google.maps.LatLng
    (28.495556906988707,76.98702201976585);

    var gps2 = new google.maps.LatLng
    (28.480029271636003,77.10198369236969);

    var distanceinMetre = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(gps1,gps2);

    alert(distanceinMetre);''
  }
  

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

the html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>direction</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapi.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAMwicCI1FnNuCLbmc6n7KLaTQsmv6UQPc&sensor=false&v=3.4&libraries=drawing,places,geometry">
      </script>
      

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you show your code to see what you already did?

Comment: CalculateDistanceWithGoogleApi(){

    var gps1 = new google.maps.LatLng
    (28.495556906988707,76.98702201976585);

    var gps2 = new google.maps.LatLng
    (28.480029271636003,77.10198369236969);

    var distanceinMetre = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(gps1,gps2);

    alert(distanceinMetre);
  }

Comment: html : <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapi.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAMwicCI1FnNuCLbmc6n7KLaTQsmv6UQPc&sensor=false&v=3.4&libraries=drawing,places,geometry">
      </script>

Comment: ,please put your code in your question.

Comment: I just put it..

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable as

```
var google;
```

but you do not initialize it before you try to reference its `maps` field. Since at that point your variable is undefined, you get an error when any members of your undefined variable is being referenced.

You will need to make sure that google maps is properly linked into your HTML and that it has been already initialized at the point when your script shared in the question is running.